# Disable accelerometer and simulate it with key inputs

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I would like to create an android app that makes the user play games requiring to tilt the screen with key inputs. 
Is it possible to simulate accelerometer data when some key is pressed? In the meantime, can I disable with some code the real accelerometer when my app is running?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I have access to the full android source, plus kernel source, so I could even add specific code or create some java code to disable or "fake" the source of accelerometer inputs.

Comment: hi @Vektor88 did you managed to do that? i have the exact same problem.

Comment: @Joe In the end I gave up and moved to another project, but you can try creating a fake accelerometer with uinput and injecting axis events. You can do this with proper key press detection and some NDK code to create the device (root is required)

Comment: Thanks. If you have pointers to any more information about this ill be very thankful.. i'm going to dig as deep as i can in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

The accelerometer is a system service, and you have no control over how other apps use it, so you cannot disable/override it.

It may be possible to fake values from it on a rooted device by writing the data to the appropriate part of the /dev/ section, but I don't know which part that is.

Comment: It would be an app that I would develop for a specific device, which comes with root by default. Is faking values for accelerometer as easy as doing `echo values > /path/to/dev` ? If i fake values then device tilting won't affect the accelerometer?

Comment: @Vektor88 Faking values like that may or may not work, but you will still be affected by the tilted device. That'll only work if the device is being held perfectly still.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have access to the full android source, plus kernel source, so I could even add specific code or create some java code to disable or "fake" the source of accelerometer inputs.

Comment: @Vektor88 That makes it much simpler. If you have control over the ROM, you can just remove the driver for the accelerometer, and write values directly into /dev/

Comment: I'd like to keep both functionalities, and decide which of the two sensor (real or fake) to enable.

Answer (score 1):

By following [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game) tutorial, you can disable Accelerometer easily.

Note the lines

```
package com.badlogic.drop;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      AndroidApplicationConfiguration config= new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
      config.useAccelerometer = false;
      config.useCompass = false;

      initialize(new Drop(), config);
   }
}
```

Thee tutorial in the link is for libgdx and libgdx is a Java game development framework that provides a unified API that works across all supported platforms including android.

Comment: But how can I disable it during run time? (in Libgdx, I mean)

Answer (score 0):

They're at least two paths to modificate your built-in sensors in raw mode:

path one: `/sys/devices/virtual/sensors/{accelerometer_sensor, proximity_sensor, etc.}`

path two:`/sys/devices/virtual/input/{input#}/`
In this case, the number represents the sensor and could be change depending on you system structure, but all built-in sensor information is inside of those folder.

Attention!

Could brick your terminal or disable the sensor, finishing in malfunction of the system OS. Make changes at your own risk.